# Linear probing hash in Mark Allen Weiss 's book

Tags: data-structures, hash, linear-probing

In *data structure and algorithm analysis in C++* 's hash related chapters, λ is the load factor of a hast table,,When the author talks about linear probing which to resolve collisions，There's a sentence I can't understand：

> We will assume a very large table and that each probe is independent
> of the previous probes. **These assumptions are satisﬁed by a random
> collision resolution strategy and are reasonable unless λ is very
> close to 1**. First, we derive the expected number of probes in an
> unsuccessful search. This is just the expected number of probes until
> we ﬁnd an empty cell. **Since the fraction of empty cells is 1 − λ, the
> number of cells we expect to probe is 1/(1 − λ).**

my questions are:

1. what is the meaning of the first bolded paragraph
2. how can I deduce 1/(1-λ)

Answer (score 0):

How many randomly-chosen cells do you need to test before you find an empty one?

If the fraction of filled slots is λ, then the probability that a randomly-chosen slot will be full is also λ.  You can find the expected number of slots you need to test by solving λ<sup>n-1</sup> = 0.5, so n = 1 + (log 0.5) / (log λ).

As long as λ is less than 0.6 or so 1/(1-λ) is a good approximation.  Here is a plot from wolfram alpha:

[image]